# Determining whether input ids are persists in directory items collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Imagine I have a `List<string> = _checkList` which represents ids for some check.

Also I have `IReadOnlyCollection<IWorkItem> = _workItems` with some work items.

Declaration of `IWorkItem`

```
 public interface IWorkItem : IDirectoryItem, INavigationItem
    {
        string ID { get; set; }

        string WorkId { get; set; }

        string Brief { get; set; } 
    }
```

I need to check if all of items with `WorkId` from `checkList` are persists in collection `_workItems`.
Should be tricky with LINQ.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `_checkList.All(c => _workItems.Any(w => w.ID == c))`? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried something? Eg `items.Where(item=>!list.Contains(item.ID))` will return all mismatches

Comment: BTW there are plenty of duplicates that show how to make this faster using a `Dictionary` or `HashSet` instead of a `List<string>`.

Comment: Can't find them. I thought about using HashSet for this. Btw, I don't need `IEnumerable` in output. Just `false` or `true` or `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the next:

`if(_checkList.All(workId => _workItems.Any(wi => wi.ID == workId))) { ... }`